# Way of creating a HTTP request which redirects in IBM Domino

Tags: java, http, redirect, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a button which is supposed to redirect a user after executing a GET request. The code for the button is below:

```
 <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:

    var redirectUrl = 'https://oursystem.ru';
    var errorRedirectUrl = 'https://oursystem.ru/errorPage';

    var EGRZAuthObject = new ru.iteko.egrz.requestprocessors.EGRZAuthorization();

    EGRZAuthObject.initializeAuthProcess(redirectUrl, errorRedirectUrl);

    }]]></xp:this.action>
 </xp:eventHandler>
```

The method looks like this:

```
public static void initializeAuthProcess(String redirectUrl, String apiRedirectUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
    String urlToGoTo = AuthURLs.ESIALoginURL(redirectUrl, apiRedirectUrl);
    System.out.println(urlToGoTo);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlToGoTo);
    HttpResponse response1 = instance.execute(httpGet);
    System.out.println("resp code " + response1.getStatusLine());
}
```

Here what happens:

1. We send a GET request to a API
2. API redirects us to another service for authorization

However, it doesn't seems to work. The request executes successfully but doesn't seem to redirect. (when we press the button). From the preceeding code we get

```
http://lk.egrz-test.i-teco.ru/fws/api/esia/login?errorRedirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru&redirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru/errorPage

resp code HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

How to make the page redirect to the resource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the goal you want to archieve. You are sending in the backend a request, but why? Shouldn't the client be sent to the URL *http://lk.egrz-test.i-teco.ru/fws/api/esia/login?errorRedirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru&redirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru/errorPage*?

Comment: And is Rus9Mus9 not working on the same problem? Maybe you should talk with him?

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with 2 different http requests here. The first Browser -> XPage and one XPage -> Backend. 
There is no code that acts on the result from the second request. You probably have a 300 class (301, 302) type response in the response1 object. You need to hand that back to the browser.

Use the context object to do that.